# Wordpress mystile theme header edit

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Right now my header in `mystile` theme looks like in picture 1, is it possible to make it look like in picture 2. In short i want to have featured banner image above the main navigation without white space between them.

Can someone please tell me the custom CSS for that or what to put in *header.php*?

Thanks a lot in advance.

#### Picture 1

[image: Picture 1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCKo5.jpg)

#### Picture 2

[image: Picture 2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ8xU.jpg)

this is my header.php

```
<?php
// File Security Check
if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) && basename( __FILE__ ) == basename( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] ) ) {
    die ( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page!' );
}
?>
<?php
/**
 * Header Template
 *
 * Here we setup all logic and XHTML that is required for the header section of all screens.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */
global $woo_options, $woocommerce;
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="<?php if ( $woo_options['woo_boxed_layout'] == 'true' ) echo 'boxed'; ?> <?php if (!class_exists('woocommerce')) echo 'woocommerce-deactivated'; ?>">
<head>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

<title><?php woo_title(''); ?></title>
<?php woo_meta(); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" media="screen" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php
    wp_head();
    woo_head();
?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php woo_top(); ?>

<div id="wrapper">



    <div id="top">
        <nav class="col-full" role="navigation">
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'has_nav_menu' ) && has_nav_menu( 'top-menu' ) ) { ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'top-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav fl', 'theme_location' => 'top-menu' ) ); ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php
                if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
                    echo '<ul class="nav wc-nav">';
                    woocommerce_cart_link();
                    echo '<li class="checkout"><a href="'.esc_url($woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url()).'">'.__('Checkout','woothemes').'</a></li>';
                    echo get_search_form();
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
            ?>
        </nav>
    </div><!-- /#top -->



    <?php woo_header_before(); ?>

    <header id="header" class="col-full">



        <hgroup>

             <?php
                $logo = esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png' );
                if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_logo'] ) && $woo_options['woo_logo'] != '' ) { $logo = $woo_options['woo_logo']; }
                if ( isset( $woo_options['woo_logo'] ) && $woo_options['woo_logo'] != '' && is_ssl() ) { $logo = preg_replace("/^http:/", "https:", $woo_options['woo_logo']); }
            ?>
            <?php if ( ! isset( $woo_options['woo_texttitle'] ) || $woo_options['woo_texttitle'] != 'true' ) { ?>
                <a id="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" />
                </a>
            <?php } ?>

            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            <h3 class="nav-toggle"><a href="#navigation">&#9776; <span><?php _e('Navigation', 'woothemes'); ?></span></a></h3>

        </hgroup>

        <?php woo_nav_before(); ?>

        <nav id="navigation" class="col-full" role="navigation">

            <?php
            if ( function_exists( 'has_nav_menu' ) && has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) {
                wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'main-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav fr', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) );
            } else {
            ?>
            <ul id="main-nav" class="nav fl">
                <?php if ( is_page() ) $highlight = 'page_item'; else $highlight = 'page_item current_page_item'; ?>
                <li class="<?php echo $highlight; ?>"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Home', 'woothemes' ); ?></a></li>
                <?php wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&depth=6&title_li=&exclude=' ); ?>
            </ul><!-- /#nav -->
            <?php } ?>

        </nav><!-- /#navigation -->

        <?php woo_nav_after(); ?>

    </header><!-- /#header -->

    <?php woo_content_before(); ?>
```

and i know that this control featured banner image 
but if move that line to any onther place in header.php my main navigation simply disappear. what do i miss, some codeing or?

ok i did insert featured banner image with your help but know it is in top left corner of webpage and no matter what i do it wont move to the right. its look like it take 50% of left side of page and i cant center it to the middle, any advice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit header.php and replace between
"featured banner" to "main navigation".
And for the empty space, Check theme styles in chrome inspect tool and add custom styles.
I recommend you to use child-theme, because if you modify a theme directly and it is updated, then your modifications may be lost.

Answer (score 0):

For Nav:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

For Banner:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner"></header>
```